# Why Kafka still receiving "expired" messages?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a very basic topic, with a retention period of 1 minute. I created it with:

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper $zhost --topic $name --create --partitions $partitions --replication-factor 1 --config retention.ms=60000
```

So my topic looks like this:

```
Topic: topic_quick  PartitionCount: 1   ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: retention.ms=60000
    Topic: topic_quick  Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0  Offline:
```

My producer then send a message, and after 1 minute I try to consume this message.

**Expected behaviour:**

- After 1 minute my consumer shouldn't receive the message I sent 1 minute ago because of the retention period.

**Current behaviour:**

- The consumer consumes the message after the retention period (1 minute)

How is this possible?, it seems that the retention period is not having any effect.

Comment: My answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137084/data-still-remains-in-kafka-topic-although-we-set-retention-hours-to-1h) might answer your question

Answer (score 0):

There is one probable answer that comes to my mind. In Kafka broker data is stored in topics, which consist of partitions, which finally consist of **segments**. One of a broker property that I think you should set is `log.segment.bytes`. From Confluent's "Kafka: the Definitive Guide"

> The log-retention settings previously mentioned operate on log segments, not individual messages. As messages are produced to the Kafka broker, they are appended to
> the current log segment for the partition. Once the log segment has reached the size
> specified by the log.segment.bytes parameter, which defaults to 1 GB, the log seg‐
> ment is closed and a new one is opened. Once a log segment has been closed, it can be
> considered for expiration. A smaller log-segment size means that files must be closed
> and allocated more often, which reduces the overall efficiency of disk writes.
> Adjusting the size of the log segments can be important if topics have a low produce
> rate. For example, if a topic receives only 100 megabytes per day of messages, and
> log.segment.bytes is set to the default, it will take 10 days to fill one segment. As
> messages cannot be expired until the log segment is closed, if log.retention.ms is
> set to 604800000 (1 week), there will actually be up to 17 days of messages retained
> until the closed log segment expires. This is because once the log segment is closed
> with the current 10 days of messages, that log segment must be retained for 7 days
> before it expires based on the time policy (as the segment cannot be removed until
> the last message in the segment can be expired)

Answer (score 0):

1. The purpose of 'retention.ms' is to cleanup topic's data so that too much of data doesn't become a problem for the system.
2. It doesn't strictly enforce the retention time as defined by 'retention.ms'
3. In addition to above, The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137084/data-still-remains-in-kafka-topic-although-we-set-retention-hours-to-1h) shared by Mike has good explanation of how 'retention.ms' actually works.