# How to check kafka topic's partitions memory usage?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

how can I check memory usage on specific topic's partitions in kafka? I tried this one "kafka-log-dirs.sh --describe...", but I'm not sure what output means:

```
                            "partition": "simpleTopic-8",
                            "size": 2752037376,
                            "offsetLag": 0,
                            "isFuture": false
```

What "size" means here? Is it a total memory to use on specific partition or memory usage?
I'm asking, because I set config "retention.bytes=2147483648" to this topic, so if "size" is just memory usage, my retention does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output in `size` is what you are looking for.

Your cleanup policy is still working fine although it exceeded the setting in your `retention.bytes` configuration. Keep in mind, that the LogCleaner will only remove data on old/inactive segments and `retention.bytes` does not provide a *hard* maximum. You can read more about this in another answer of mine on [Data still remains in Kafka topic even after retention time/size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137084/data-still-remains-in-kafka-topic-even-after-retention-time-size/63137573#63137573)