# Kafka Logs are not getting stored for the given retention time

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using kafka framework for a transfer of logs from producer to consumer in a project.
The log retention policies really confuse me.
The global configs in the "server.properties" shows

> log.retention.hours=168

I overrided this for a topic using the command

> /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic topic1 --config retention.ms=1000

But the logs didn't get deleted after doing this.
Then I've changed the global config in the "server.properties" file to

> log.retention.ms=1000

And

> log.segment.bytes=1073741824

And

> log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

I've restarted kafka but the logs aren't deleted even after 300 seconds
So I reseted the retention time

> log.retention.hours = 168

I also changed the retention time in dynamic config to 1hr

---

The next day, all the logs in the topic just disappared.
Now the logs aren't getting stored even for 1 hour.
The dynamic config shows

> Topic: SyslogNATSrv    PartitionCount: 1    ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: cleanup.policy=delete,retention.ms=3600000,delete.retention.ms=3600000
>
> Dynamic configs for topic SyslogNATSrv are:
> cleanup.policy=delete sensitive=false synonyms={DYNAMIC_TOPIC_CONFIG:cleanup.policy=delete, DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.cleanup.policy=delete}
> retention.ms=3600000 sensitive=false synonyms={DYNAMIC_TOPIC_CONFIG:retention.ms=3600000}
> delete.retention.ms=3600000 sensitive=false synonyms={DYNAMIC_TOPIC_CONFIG:delete.retention.ms=3600000, DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000}

And the "server.properties" shows

> log.retention.hours=168

I don't understand why the logs are not getting stored even for 1 hour(not even 1 second). They should be stored for 1hour if it follows dynamic config or 7 days if it follows global config.

Please help me with this!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data still remains in Kafka topic even after retention time/size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137084/data-still-remains-in-kafka-topic-even-after-retention-time-size)

Comment: How do you check the records in the topic?

Comment: @JavierYáñez I have a consumer code which reads and prints the logs from topics

Comment: @mike As i said in the second half of my post, the logs are not getting stored even for 1 second now. How would I deal with that